# ¿Se puede evitar que mi app tome la fuente de letra del sistema operativo en android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Lo que pasa es que si el usuario cambia la fuente de su dispositivo, tambien cambia la fuente de mi app. ¿Se puede evitar esto?

Este es el textview que quiero poner, pero cuando lo simulo en mi movil, el tipo de letra aparce diferente, y esto es porq en el sistema operativo el estilo de la fuente es  "choco cooky"

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtNombre"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/height_nombre_margin"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Jhon Alexander"
        android:textColor="#f4f4f4"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_nombre_margin"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para dar una fuente personalizada a tu app sigue los siguientes pasos:

#### A. Configuraciones con respecto a la fuente

1. Si en la carpeta `res` de tu app no existe un directorio llamado `font` debes crearlo. Puedes hacer clic derecho sobre **`res`**, luego seleccionas **`New`** y luego **`Directory`**, dándole el nombre de **`font`** al directorio
2. Colocas en ese directorio el (los) archivo(s) que contiene(n) tu(s) fuente(s). Ojo, debes usar esta convención para nombrarlos o te dará error: `nombre_detalle`, por ejemplo: `roboto_regular.ttf`
3. En el directorio `font` recién creado, creas ahora un archivo de recurso de fuente. Puedes hacerlo dando clic derecho sobre el directorio **`font`**, luego seleccionas **`New`** y luego seleccionas **`Font resource file`**. Cuando te pida el nombre lo escribes. Escribe un nombre *coherente*  con tu tipo de fuente. Si estamos trabajando con Roboto, puedes llamarle **`roboto.xml`**

   Dentro de ese archivo puedes poner varias referencias a tu fuente. Ojo, todas las referencias que pongas ahí, deben existir como archivos de fuente. Por ejemplo, si pones el código de más abajo, debes tener estos tres archivos en `font`: `roboto_regular.ttf, roboto_italic.ttf, roboto_black.ttf`.

Código para poner en `roboto.xml`, que sería nuestro archivo de ejemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <font
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        android:font="@font/roboto_regular" />
    <font
        android:fontStyle="italic"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        android:font="@font/roboto_italic" />
    <font
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="700"
        android:font="@font/roboto_black" />

</font-family>
```

---

#### B. Configuación en el `TextView`

Ahora sólo indicas en el `TextView` que quieres que use un tipo de fuente determinado, agregándole el atributo `fontFamily`, por ejemplo:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtNombre"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/height_nombre_margin"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Jhon Alexander"
        android:textColor="#f4f4f4"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_nombre_margin"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

O lo puedes hacer por programación:

```
mTextView =  findViewById(R.id.tuTextView);
mTypeFace = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.roboto_regular);
mTextView.setTypeface(mTypeFace);
```

Cuando pones esto `@font/roboto_regular` en el XML del `TextView`, o pones esto por programación `R.font.roboto_regular`, estás indicando que quieres la fuente con las definiciones indicadas en archivo creado en la etapa **`A3`** más arriba. O sea, la fuente `roboto_regular`, con un estilo `normal` y un peso de `400`.

Et voilà, a disfrutar de tu fuente Roboto :)

Te dejo una imagen sobre cómo quedaría la carpeta `font` en resources:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Puedes ver la [documentacion oficial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml) de Android

En el directorio `res` podes crear el directorio `font`
y agregarle archivos de fuentes `.tff` y `.otf`

luego podes crear un `xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <font
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        android:font="@font/lobster_regular" />
    <font
        android:fontStyle="italic"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        android:font="@font/lobster_italic" />
</font-family>
```

y en tu vista puedes setear la propiedad `android:fontFamily`

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/lobster"/>
```

o en `style`

```
<style name="customfontstyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/lobster</item>
</style>
```

tambien se puede programaticamente

```
val typeface = resources.getFont(R.font.myfont)
textView.typeface = typeface
```

existe una libreria de soporte

> La biblioteca de soporte 26.0 proporciona soporte para la función
>   Fuentes en XML en dispositivos que ejecutan Android 4.1 (nivel de API
>   16) y superior.

```
val typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.myfont)
```