# ¿Cómo crear un nuevo estilo de fuente personalizada en Android?

Tags: android

Tengo el siguiente código para personalizar el tipo de fuente en un proyecto de Android:

Este es para asignar el tipo de fuente:

```
public final class CustomFont {

    private static final String fontPathNormal = "fonts/SourceSansProLight.ttf";
    private static final String fontPathBold = "fonts/SourceSansProSemiBold.ttf";
    private static final String fontPathRegular = "fonts/SourceSansProRegular.ttf";
    private static final String fontPathNormalItalic = "fonts/SourceSansProLightItalic.ttf";

    public static Typeface getFontNormal(Context context) {
        return Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), fontPathNormal);
    }

    public static Typeface getFontBold(Context context) {
        return Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), fontPathBold);
    }

    public static Typeface getFontRegular(Context context) {
        return Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), fontPathRegular);
    }

    public static Typeface getFontNormalItalic(Context context) {
        return Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), fontPathNormalItalic);
    }
}
```

Y con esto creo un control para no tener que asignar el `Typeface` a cada TextView creado.

```
public class MyTextView extends AppCompatTextView {

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            Typeface tf;

            switch (getTypeface().getStyle()) {
                case Typeface.BOLD:
                    tf = CustomFont.getFontBold(getContext());
                    break;

                case Typeface.ITALIC:
                    tf = CustomFont.getFontNormalItalic(getContext());
                    break;

                case Typeface.NORMAL:
                    tf = CustomFont.getFontRegular(getContext());
                    break;

                default:
                    tf = CustomFont.getFontNormal(getContext());
                    break;
            }

            setTypeface(tf);
        }
    }
}
```

Con esto solo creo los `MyTextView` y ya aparecen con la fuente que quiero, pero solo le puedo asignar tres tipos de estilos `BOLD, ITALIC Y NORMAL`.

```
<ec.ffweb.ruedas.Helper.MyTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Texto de prueba"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

La pregunta es: ¿Cómo puedo agregar otro estilo como por ejemplo `LIGHT` o `SEMIBOLD`?

Comment: Tienes que agregar los archivos de fuente (si no los tienes agregados)  y crear un recurso de fuente (XML)  y dentro de él los diferentes estilos de fuente que luego podrás usar. Creo que [aquí queda explicado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/207925/29967) de una forma clara y gráfica.

Comment: @A.Cedano ¿Se puede utilizar con Android Studio 2.3.3?

Comment: No creo que haya problemas para usar fuentes personalizadas con Android Studio 2.3.3 de la forma explicada. Lo importante es que observes las normas indicadas y pongas los archivos en los directorios correctos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tienes las fuentes dentro de /font/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

puedes referenciarlas directamente:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/SourceSansProLightItalic"/>
```

o puedes crear una mezcla de varias, creando un archivo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <font
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        android:font="@font/SourceSansProSemiBold" />
    <font
        android:fontStyle="italic"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        android:font="@font/SourceSansProLightItalic" />
</font-family>
```

y referenciarlas desde tu TextView:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisa:

[Fuentes en XML (inglés)](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml)

Comment: ¿Se puede usar en Android Studio 2.3.3?

Comment: En realidad no depende de la versión de android studio pero si del targetsdk definido que debe ser minimo 26 y minsk API level 16

Comment: Aún en versiones anteriores se puede usar mediante *Support Library*, ([ver aquí](https://segunfamisa.com/posts/custom-fonts-with-android-support-library))

Comment: Usando Support Library, aunque pueda usarse en versiones inferiores a 16, algunas de estas versiones no realizan el cambio en la fuente, he probado en Android OS 2.3 :-(.